# Setting up an email alert when a question is tagged with a particular tag?

Tags: support, feature-request

Is it possible to set up an alert when a question is tagged with a particular tag? For example, a user posts a new question and tags it with 'php'. I then get an email alert to say a new 'php' question has been posted which gives me the chance to answer it.

Comment: Yes indeed, it's called "Filtered Questions" and you can start here: http://stackexchange.com/filters. Create new filter, choose the tag and you'll get emails. No instant email though, most you can achieve is every 15 minutes.

Comment: @ShadowWizard - Is there any way to subscribe not just to tags but to particular search terms (the message body should also be searched, automatically) which are not particularly tags? Tags are quite common, while some specific terms may not be tags.

Comment: @Maxim I'm afraid not. It was [suggested and declined in the past](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5857/rss-feed-for-searches) to add RSS feeds for search results, as far as I know, nothing has changed on that regard.