# What can be done to prevent unintentional tag misuse?

Tags: discussion, tags

This is regarding the general problem of people misusing tags. As per my observation, this happens when old tag is used to tag a question which 
is related to a newer library/technology of similar name. There can be other reasons for incorrect tags, but this is one situation I've come across.

I have seen this problem in [ribbon vs netflix-ribbon](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/364121/disambiguating-the-ribbon-tag-microsoft-tabs-interface-or-netflix-loadbalance) and [zuul vs netflix-zuul](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/364086/disambiguating-the-zuul-tag-api-gateway-or-javascript-testing-framework). 
Users don't read tag description before using them to tag questions. And in such cases, it's very counter-intuitive to give attention to tag 
description so it's not their fault also. Most people will miss this.

[ribbon](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ribbon) has been here since last 10 years. [netflix-ribbon](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/netflix-ribbon) is a new library.

A user, who has never heard of ribbon interface by Microsoft, types a question related to ribbon load-balancer. While adding tags user 
types ribbon in tag-editor, and [ribbon](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ribbon) appears in dropdown. User selects [ribbon](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ribbon) tag (and sometimes [netflix-ribbon](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/netflix-ribbon) also). 
Now we have a question which is wrongly tagged [ribbon](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ribbon).

If someone has [set email alerts](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/265551/setting-up-an-email-alert-when-a-question-is-tagged-with-a-particular-tag) for the [ribbon](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ribbon) tag, his inbox is now filled with load-balancer questions, which is not good.

I can't think of a straight forward solution for this. But I feel following points can help:

- While creating new tags, users *should* check if there is an existing tag with a very similar name. Logic can be added in SO back-end to do the same.
- Older tag can be prefixed before creating newer tag. [ribbon](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ribbon) could be renamed as [microsoft-ribbon]. [zuul](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/zuul) can be renamed [javascript-zuul].
- Question askers *should* be given some sort of warning-esque message to verify the tags if there is a tag with similar name.

Comment: Questioners almost never get this wrong.  They instinctively know that,say, [wpf][ribbon] is most likely to get them enough views and an answer and that [wpf-ribbon] gets them zilch.  That the email subscription service is too lame to deal with this is an issue unrelated to tag usage.

Comment: Any solution that requires me to read the description of the tag is destined to fail.  I kind of agree with @HansPassant that the problem here is that the email notifications are pretty simplistic.

Comment: The only way to "solve" this would be if SO created some kind of tag-pair-filter (e.g. "you have tagged this [python] and [Unity3D], these two tags are not typically associated together, did you mean [C#]?"), but I doubt SO wants to do that.

Comment: As somebody who almost daily sees people using [batch-file] instead of [batch-processing], I wish you luck with this.

Comment: As somebody who almost daily see people using [sse] instead of [server-sent-events], I wish you luck with this.

Comment: @HansPassant What you said is correct. The issue is not that. Issue is : people using incorrect tag *probably* thinking that is the correct tag. *Why would anybody want to tag a question related to cloud tech with a ui-element related tag?* Doesn't make sense. So I think questioner is at fault here for not reading the tag description.

Comment: And email problem is a side effect of this.

Comment: @Draco18s If we can report some more tags with similar problems, then maybe SO might consider implementing this.

Comment: Shameless self-promotion: I wrote a [proposed FAQ/attempt at a canonical post](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/354427/how-do-i-avoid-misusing-tags) about how to avoid tag misuse.

Comment: What about renaming [tag:ribbon] to [tag:wpf-ribbon] and blacklist the former? I think the first thing to do is to have unambiguous tag names. If that's not enough, then we should investigate more complex solutions.

Answer (score 13):

People occasionally post questions about [Hazelcast IMap](http://docs.hazelcast.org/docs/3.8/javadoc/com/hazelcast/core/IMap.html) and tag them imap. The inappropriately tagged questions almost always mention "hazelcast" or one of a few other words in the text.

SO ought to have a blocker list per tag, "don't suggest tag x if the question mentions any of these words". For ribbon, "netflix", "spring",  and "java" looks like good blocker words. Of course users could add the tag themselves; it's legal to ask a question about Netflix and Excel. SO just shouldn't lead people into that.

Comment: Rather than outright failing to suggest them, perhaps a small UI tweak such as coloring them differently or sticking them on a separate line would be sufficient. Simply communicate to the user that *these aren't the tags you're looking for*. The process could even be community driven, with the blacklists similar to the existing synonym lists.

Answer (score 8):

In my experience, the real problem is that many users *don't* do what you say: they never look at or interact with the tag selection menu in any way, but simply type a couple of more or less random words into the tag box, and the SE interface happily turns their scribbling into tags.

So they type in "netflix ribbon" and the system turns that into [ribbon](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ribbon) [netflix](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/netflix) without the user ever having to read or click any tag descriptions, or possibly even notice that they exist (if they type fast enough and/or have a slow enough Internet connection that the menu doesn't have time to load).  Or they type in "java for loop step size" and (due to automatic tag synonyms and sorting) end up with [java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/java) [loops](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/loops) [for-loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/for-loop) [size](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/size) [step](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/step) (and then somebody has to keep cleaning up the [step](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/step) tag, which is *supposed* to be about the ISO 10303 *STandard for the Exchange of Product data*).

One of the telltale signs of this is when the tags for a question exactly match the words in its title or its first sentence (except for their order, of course).  Another common sign is the complete absence of any hyphenated tags, although tag synonyms can sometimes automatically introduce them, as in the example above.

Honestly, IMO, if people *were* forced to actually do tagging like you describe it (i.e. to actually wait for the dropdown menu to open and to confirm their tag selection from that menu), that alone would probably cut down on a lot of incorrect tagging.

(Of course, there would still have to be some mechanism for users with [that privilege](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/create-tags) to add new tags.  But that's probably something that *should* require an explicit confirmation of intent anyway.)

Comment: If you want a tag to be used correctly, you have to exploit the system to make sure that it would never be used incorrectly. Path of least resistance and all that.

Answer (score 1):

Set a requirement for users to set tags (i.e. min XX rep). However, users can *suggest* tags regardless of their rep, which then users with **high** rep can accept them as appropriate tags.

As for how the posts will appear under tags, there can be a checkbox to 'hide' tags that are not accepted. In addition, suggested tags will have a lighter grey colour/faded, and users can opt to not receive email notifications on suggested tags (which seems to be the main issue).

To reward and promote a better tagging system, a +1 rep can be given to users whose tags are accepted per question with a cap of 3 per day (discourage spam), while a -1 rep can be imposed for continuous inappropriate tags (cap of -5 before having a you-can-only-suggest-tags-now ban for a week).

Users who accept tags may be awarded badges for accepting tags for glory and not for rep. ;)

For the minimum, a rep of 50 would be reasonable, since there is already a penalty for inappropriate tagging.

Comment: It sounds like you are suggesting that high rep users should (in effect) be gate keepers of low reps user's posting.  It wouldn't work.  Not enough high-rep users with 1) the time / energy to do this essentially boring task, 2) the detailed knowledge of the domains / tags to do it properly.

Answer (score -2):

> What can be done to prevent unintentional tag misuse?

The users can be displayed an overlay with the tag wiki and excerpt when they use the tag first time.
The user will read the wiki, then press `Post your question` at the under of the overlay and the question will be posted.

Answer (score -3):

> What can be done to prevent unintentional tag misuse?

The same thing that we have been doing since forever: disambiguation.

If you make it plain obvious what the tag is about, at first blush, it's very unlikely that the asker would misuse the tag.

Comment: You're right. But users will keep creating confusing tags and questioners will keep adding incorrect tags. Some users will raise disambiguation requests, mods will have to weight-in and then [some of us will have to clean up already asked questions](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/364142/3679857). If we can prevent (or make difficult) creation of confusing tags, it should solve the problem (though not 100%).

Comment: @narendra-choudhary well, you need 1.5k reputation to *create a tag* on SO. There's a group of users that one of their life missions is checking the [new tags](https://stackoverflow.com/tags?tab=new) page. BUT! SO is the biggest site on the network, it needs meat to deal with its problems.