# Measures to reduce misuse of python-3.x tag?

Tags: discussion, tags

Nowadays the presence of the `[python-3.x]` tag

> [[...] has the clear advantage that it visually separates users who know what they are doing from [users] who tag with all they can find.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/365015/usefulness-of-the-python-3-x-tag#comment567851_365015) – [usr2564301](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/2564301/usr2564301)

On the other hand, in many cases I feel compelled to edit the tags and remove the *unnecessary* reference to a specific version of Python.

What can be done to reduce the incidence of misusing the `[python-3.x]` tag?

---

<sub>The question "[What can be done to prevent unintentional tag misuse?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/364122/what-can-be-done-to-prevent-unintentional-tag-misuse)"
and its answers are related but the focus of the question and the solutions proposed in the answers do not seem applicable to this specific issue.

Possibly the question "[Display a popup when a low-reputation user tags a question with a frequently-misused tag](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/347903/display-a-popup-when-a-low-reputation-user-tags-a-question-with-a-frequently-mis)" outlines a realistic solution.</sub>

Comment: Leave comments - lots of them. There's nothing that really can be done without a warning implemented by SE, but like all IDE tags, some people just won't get the message.

Comment: Is this really that big a problem? When a question might have a modicum of chance of being useful and lasting, just edit the tags and be done with it.

Comment: Note that it is the *question asker* who misses out on attention from experts here (not me, I include all versions in my custom question filter).

Comment: I might not be using perfect analogy, but we use macos in almost every Mac related question, and then use specific version to which the problem is related. What is the harm in using python and python 3-x both?

Comment: @ankii: I think gboffi's objection is to only using [tag:python-3.x] and forgetting to include the [tag:python] tag.

Comment: @MartijnPieters:  Oh It wasn't immediately clear to me. But still I answered in favour of using two tags. Its enforcement seems easy to do using edits and conveying to edit reviewers.

Comment: @MartijnPieters to clarify my stance:  ① generic question, only `[python]` ② version-specific question `[python-3.x]` or `[python-3.x] [python]` — The misuse, in my view, consists in using either `[python-3.x]` or `[python-3.x] [python]`  in a vanilla generic question...

Comment: @gboffi: so? Most **don't know the difference** or think they need to distinguish from Python 2 *just in case*.

Comment: @gboffi: why label this as misuse? It is easily corrected, most users pick up, after one or two such nudges, how to use the tags correctly. It's really not a big deal. It's not as if they are breaking the site or fraudulently working around system limitations to gain reputation, putting their question in front of the wrong people, etc.

Answer (score 2):

It doesn't seem like that big of an issue. Just leave a comment explaining the proper usage.

You can always remove the [python-3.x](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/python-3.x) tag if it irks you very much.